# Catch click/touch event before keyboard when it's enabled - iPad and TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ipad, web

iPad issue - expert wanted.

I'm making a small website.
As part of the web the user types text using TinyMCE, and I wrap this text in html tags. When the user **clicks** one of the tags, an event is fired.

so far, all is good, BUT, when using iPad, once the keyboard is down (disabled) the event is fired as expected, but if the keyboard is up and the user **touches** one of the tags, the event is not working at all.

I need both the event and the keyboard - Is there a way to fire an event before the keyboard catches it using JavaScript/jQuery or any other web language?